# javascript object didn't work

Tags: javascript

what's wrong here? and what is the different if I declared like this

```
mat.prototype = function discountedMat(){

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tu8tS/

```
function mat(brick,sand,water) {
    this.mat = brick;
    this.sand = sand;
    this.water = water;

    var cal = function(){
        return this.mat * this.sand * this.water;
    };
}

var material = new mat(44,2,9);
console.log(material.cal());
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I think this answer can help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Comment: its all about scope chk this answer to understand http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking why `material.cal()` fails,

it is because,

```
var cal = function(){
```

`cal` is just a local variable in the `mat` function, it will not be exposed in the objects, created with `mat` function constructor. To fix that, add the function definition to the current object, like this

```
this.cal = function(){
```

It is normally good and efficient to define the methods as part of the protoype, like this

```
mat.prototype.cal = function() {
    ...
}
```

because, you don't have to create a function object every time the function constructor is called.

Answer (score 1):

You just declared a local variable `cal` inside the `mat` function.

The normal practice is declaring it on the `prototype` of the function.

```
function mat(brick,sand,water) {
    this.mat = brick;
    this.sand = sand;
    this.water = water;   
}

mat.prototype.cal = function(){
    return this.mat * this.sand * this.water;
};
```

Comment: I've seen some code use function within a function, just like I did cal in mat function, what do you think it does?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/8jC22/)

JS:

```
function mat(brick,sand,water) {
    this.mat = brick;
    this.sand = sand;
    this.water = water;

    this.cal = function(){
        return this.mat * this.sand * this.water;
    };

}

var material = new mat(44,2,9);
 console.log(material.cal());
```

Comment: what is this version versus the prototype version?

Comment: Here i added the cal function definition to the current object by using "this"